# How to run script in OpenVMS?

Tags: java, openvms

Good Day, I have a problem executing Java Application on OpenVMS.
I have this app.exe (for Windows) and app.sh (for Linux).

Can you help me how to run this on OpenVMS Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, neither an app.exe (for Windows) or app.sh (for Linux) are Java apps.
They may contain activation code for a Java app.
For OpenVMS (just like any other platform) you activate a Java app by invoking the runtime system for example with a command like -
$ JAVAC -CLASSPATH <...stuff.jar...>  javasscriptsource.JAVA
or
$ JAR

Now for longer, more complex command lines you may well capture those in a helper DCL script which would typically be a ".COM" file.

Please Google "Java on OpenVMS" for some hints and a pointer to a useful book:
https://www.theminimumyouneedtoknow.com/java_book.html

Comment: so @app.exe or app.sh will not work? can you help me with sample command on how to run?

Comment: Open up that SH file and see what it does. It seems you are not the correct person to be tasked to get this going, escalate to management.

Comment: Check out your shell and how to log the executed commands and their arguments. For bash it is -x. Then you will see the full java command, which you need to use/translate on/for VMS. FWIW, JAVAC invokes the java compiler. You very likely don't need it. And even if, you probably do not want to compile a "scriptsource". On VMS just run JAVA and you will see the possible arguments.